# Postgres - best approach to manage the order of items in binding table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 3 tables: `products`, `images` and a `product_images` binding table. I'd like to give my users the ability to control the order of the images in the binding table and I am wondering what the best approach is to handle this on db level?

The obvious answer is to have a `position` column in the binding table with each `product`'s record having a sequentially ascending integer that identifies the record's position in `products.images`. However I am wondering if there is a better approach that I haven't thought of yet?

I am sure that this question has been answered already, so I apologise for that, but I am having difficulty finding it!

Comment: *Better* is very blurred term. Please, describe what do you think is wrong with this approach and what the feature you want to achieve by selecting *better* way. In general, better way is to keep it simple: it should be straightforward  with no need to find the reason you've chosen some special way to handle simple tasks

Comment: Also please check this article: *[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)*

Comment: You're right, better/best are rather subjective terms. My feeling with the my originally thought approach is that updating one item in the binding table will result in needing to update all other related entities in the binding table as well and perhaps this could be avoided by some nifty Postgres feature that I am unaware of.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: The key point here is that relational table is an unordered set of rows, so: 1) no any ordering exists unless `order by` part of select is present; 2) rows are not related to each other and "know nothing" about other rows. That's why you need to explicitly use some criteria to provide ordering: you can update all the changed records with new ordering position or you may store ordering information as sorted array and then do unnest.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for furthering my understanding.